Using PowerShell to Select Value from Disjoined Inner XML Namespace
I am working with an XML document that has disjoined nested namespaces. Using a Powershell script, I need to loop through the XML nodes and select a value from each of the inner namespaces.
The problem I am having is that the value returned is always from the first set of data within the inner namespace.
Here is a representation of the XML file named nsTest.xml:
<ns1:Root xmlns:ns1="example.com\ns1" xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2" XsdSchemaValidatable="true">
  <ns1:DataSet>
    <ns1:TimeStamp>
      <ns2:Time>2023-06-01T08:00:00</ns2:Time>
    </ns1:TimeStamp>
  </ns1:DataSet>
  <ns1:DataSet>
    <ns1:TimeStamp>
      <ns2:Time>2024-07-02T08:00:00</ns2:Time>
    </ns1:TimeStamp>
  </ns1:DataSet>
 </ns1:Root>

Here is the PowerShell script I am using:
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
[Xml]$XMLData = Get-Content "nsTest.xml"

$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XMLData.NameTable)
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns1", "example.com\ns1")
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "example.com\ns2")

$DataSets = $XMLData.SelectNodes("//ns1:Root/ns1:DataSet", $nsmgr)

Write-Host ("The number of items in the dataset is: " + $DataSets.Count)

Write-Host ("DataSets [0] is: " + $DataSets[0].SelectSingleNode("//ns1:TimeStamp/ns2:Time", $nsmgr).InnerText)
Write-Host ("DataSets [1] is: " + $DataSets[1].SelectSingleNode("//ns1:TimeStamp/ns2:Time", $nsmgr).InnerText)

Write-Host $DataSets[0].InnerXml
Write-Host $DataSets[1].InnerXml

Here are the results I am getting:
The number of items in the dataset is: 2
DataSets [0] is: 2023-06-01T08:00:00
DataSets [1] is: 2023-06-01T08:00:00
<ns1:TimeStamp xmlns:ns1="example.com\ns1"><ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2023-06-01T08:00:00</ns2:Time></ns1:TimeStamp>
<ns1:TimeStamp xmlns:ns1="example.com\ns1"><ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2024-07-02T08:00:00</ns2:Time></ns1:TimeStamp>

Here is what I would have expected to see:
The number of items in the dataset is: 2
DataSets [0] is: 2023-06-01T08:00:00
DataSets [1] is: 2024-07-02T08:00:00
<ns1:TimeStamp xmlns:ns1="example.com\ns1"><ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2023-06-01T08:00:00</ns2:Time></ns1:TimeStamp>
<ns1:TimeStamp xmlns:ns1="example.com\ns1"><ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2024-07-02T08:00:00</ns2:Time></ns1:TimeStamp>

I have tried using the [local-name() = 'Time'] convention instead of specifying the namespace, but that didn't make a difference.
Is there something about XML namespaces that I am not understanding?


Pragmatically speaking, you can use PowerShell's adaption of the XML DOM,[1] which is namespace-agnostic, in combination with member-access enumeration:
# -> 2
$xmlData.Root.DataSet.Count

# -> @('2023-06-01T08:00:00', '2024-07-02T08:00:00')
$xmlData.Root.DataSet.TimeStamp.Time

# -> @(
#     '<ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2023-06-01T08:00:00</ns2:Time>',
#     '<ns2:Time xmlns:ns2="example.com\ns2">2024-07-02T08:00:00</ns2:Time>'
#    )
$xmlData.Root.DataSet.TimeStamp.InnerXml 


As for what you tried:
By starting your XPath query with //, you're starting the search at the root of the entire document rather than from the node on which you call .SelectSingleNode(), so the same node - under the first dataset - is found in both calls.
Simply use a relative path to avoid this problem, i.e. omit //:
# ...

# Note that "//" has been removed from the paths.
Write-Host ("DataSets [0] is: " + $DataSets[0].SelectSingleNode("ns1:TimeStamp/ns2:Time", $nsmgr).InnerText)
Write-Host ("DataSets [1] is: " + $DataSets[1].SelectSingleNode("ns1:TimeStamp/ns2:Time", $nsmgr).InnerText)

# ...


[1] In essence, PowerShell allows you to treat any parsed [xml] document as an object graph that you can drill into using regular dot notation, because PowerShell surfaces XML (child) elements and XML attributes as namespace-less properties on each object (XML node) in the graph.
See the third section of this answer for details.

I had actually tried using the dot notation initially but it seemed to behave differently for XML documents that used nested namespaces compared to those that did not use namespaces.  In any case, it was a simple misunderstanding  on my part.  I had erroneously been assuming that starting my XPath query with // was selecting the root of the XML elements represented by $DataSets, but as you pointed out, it was actually selecting the root of the document as the starting point.  Thank you for catching this as it was driving me nuts.  +1 and accepted answer.

My pleasure, @jwitt98, and thanks for accepting. That's strange that you saw a difference in dot-notation behavior between docs with and without namespaces; my understanding is that namespaces are simply ignored.
